# Windows Authentication and IS_MEMBER() function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have an internal domain and an external one (for customers) that trusts the internal one (one way trust). I guess this is the case in many organizations.

We have a problem with the IS_MEMBER() function in SQL Server 2014, where the function doesn't seem to see the external domain. 
It fails on various servers where SQL Server 2014 is installed, not just on some arbitrary one. Within the same domain controller, 
the function is working fine in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Do you have any hints to help me resolve the problem ?

Comment: Check this to see if it helps. From Aaron Bertrand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836011/how-to-get-the-equivalent-of-is-member-for-a-certain-user-using-windows-login

Comment: Thanks for you help Aaron. To be more clear, this is the way I am testing with a remote connection with SSMS. I am expecting a result of 1 (true) in both call because I am in the group.
    
    SELECT SUSER_NAME(), IS_MEMBER('External\GroupName'), IS_MEMBER('Internal\GroupName');

Comment: Problem solve. This was related to the Kerberos protocol, cross domain and NTLM protocol for authentication to work properly.